# How can I get a number with arbitrary accuracy?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

Here I got a list `` list={-0.9829438571943362`, -0.9829438571866701`, -0.9829438572897751`, 0.9829438568473774`, 0.9829438572472889`, 0.9829438568287702`, 0.9829438566723963`, 0.982943857276141`}; `` I want it to be less precise like `{-0.9829,-0.9829,-0.9829,0.9829,0.9829,0.9829,0.9829,0.9829};` so that I could
use `DeleteDuplicates` to elimate the same number to get `{-0.9829,0.9829}`. To do that I use `SetPrecision[list,4](*Out:{-0.9829,-0.9829,-0.9829,0.9829,0.9829,0.9829,0.9829,0.9829}*)`, but `SetPrecision` only changes the display form of the number instead of the actual size because `DeleteDuplicates[SetPrecision[list,4]](*Out:{-0.9829,-0.9829,-0.9829,0.9829,0.9829,0.9829,0.9829,0.9829}*)`. So my question is how can I change the accuracy of a number( I mean change the actual size of number)?

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetAccuracy.html)?

Comment: @Roman. Sure I've looked at the doc and it didn't help me.

Comment: "What's happening here?" - it is not obvious to me that there is a problem. Could you specifically say which part of that result is problematic for you?

Comment: @MarcoB. Okay, I edited my question so that you can see my problem clearly

Comment: On version 12.1 on Linux (64-bit), `DeleteDuplicates[SetPrecision[list, 4]]` returns only the two element list desired, so there might be something a bit more complicated going on here?

Comment: @eyorble. Indeed, I get the desired list after closing and reopening MMA. But what if the list is a complex list? You can try this list ```{-0.9829438571943362` - 0.1738913804515506` I, -0.9829438571866701` - 
  0.1738913805391788` I, -0.9829438572897751` + 
  0.17389137936063287` I, 0.9829438568473774` + 0.173891384417482` I, 
 0.9829438572472889` - 0.17389137984627148` I, 
 0.9829438568287702` - 0.17389138463017287` I, 
 0.9829438566723963` - 0.17389138641761434` I, 
 0.982943857276141` - 0.17389137951647776` I}``` with precision of 4.

Comment: Worth noting that all of these fail `SameQ`, but that `Equal` works; `DeleteDuplicates[SetPrecision[list, 4], #1 == #2 &]` collapses the list.

Comment: @thorimur. Thanks a lot. But I get confused about what the difference between ```#1 == #2 &``` and ```SameQ``` is in this situation. Could you explain that to me?

Comment: Quantum life, syntactically, the differences is that `#1 == #2 &` is `Equal[#1, #2]&` and `SameQ[#1, #2]&` is `#1 === #2 &`.

Comment: `SameQ` (also written `===`) (which is what I think `DeleteDuplicates` uses to check equivalence) checks if two expressions are literally the same mma expression. `Equal` (also written `==`) merely checks if two expressions are "equal", and for numbers that means numerically equal. So for example, `0 == 0.00` is `True` but `0 === 0.00` is `False`. The one exception to this is that two `Real` numbers are still `SameQ` if they differ only in their last binary digit. So confusingly, `SameQ[SetPrecision[2, 5], SetPrecision[2, 1]]` is `True`...I still need to understand this better, to be honest.

Comment: @CATrevillian@thorimur. Thank you, I think I understand what you said.